# Downloading PDF report from kibana/elasticsearch using API call

Tags: api, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-7

I am trying to generate PDF reports and download them using a script. I followed below instructions.

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/docs/user/reporting/automating-report-generation.asciidoc

I am able to queue the report and i also got a download url ()/api/.../download/xyzdrfd but when i am trying wget on the url, It's not working. I have no idea how to download that report using APIs so just tried with wget.

Can anyone tell me how to download the reports from API call?

Comment: this is exactly the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69174636/elastic-search-kibana-pdf-report

Comment: Yes, Its the same. Just waiting for an answer to make this as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download might not be happening due to some redirects happening on the page. Use `-L` option with `curl` command to get it working. I did it specifically using the Kibana endpoint to download a PDF file. Replace the `username` and `passsword` with the basic auth credentials of yours. Use `-o` option to specify the downloaded file name. Below is the complete example of the command:

```
curl -L -u username:password -o download.pdf https://endpoint.com:9244/s/bi-/api/reporting/jobs/download/ktl8n95q001edfc210feaz0r
```